# TIMESTAMPDIFF() usage

Tags: mysql, sql

I am struggling making sense of the TIMESTAMPDIFF() function using MYsql

here is an example:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,start_time,end_time) AS Duration
FROM exam_answers
LIMIT 200;
```

Can someone explain to me what this is doing and what the purpose of me using it is? is their easier code? is this commonly used in business settings?

Thanks.

Comment: It is getting the difference between two date/time values in minutes.  Is that hard to understand?

Comment: How are you having difficulty with *give me the difference in minutes between start_time and _end time, in a column you can call "duration", and give me 200 rows, from the table exam_answers*?

Comment: perhaps because this is for a class i am taking and am thinking of its future uses.

Comment: It's still unclear why you're having difficulty. Yes, you would use it in business settings, whenever you need to determine the difference between two timestamps, in a specified unit of measure (minutes, days, weeks, months, years, etc.). You can't see any uses for that in business? *How many days does it take us to process an order from the date it is taken until it actually ships?*, for instance?

Comment: When I'm writing queries, I frequently look at this page in the MySQL online manual. I've been writing queries for years, and I still refer to it all the time. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html It's worth reading through once as you're learning.

Comment: Thanks O. It is always good to have as many resources as possible. appreciate that.

Comment: Also do you always need to use the AS or TIMESTAMPDIFF when using AVG, MIN, MAX functions?

Comment: Please be mroe specific what you are looking for. For example "is there easier code" - to do what?

Comment: Joseph the AS is just aliasing the column. It will default to (no column name) if you don't give it one. The AS is also optional to do this. You don't always HAVE to give it a column name but it is required when it's used in a CTE or sub-query, or returned in a function, etc. So more often than not.... it's best practice to get in a habit of doing it always.

Answer (score 0):

All this is doing is running a calculation on two fields in your data. So the function is returning the difference between the second and third parameters in the units defined by the first parameter.

`TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2011-12-10', '2011-12-20')`

will return 10. Because there are 10 days between Dec 10th and Dec 20th. That value is retrieved as Duration (just an alias).

Comment: Thanks this helps tremendously. Their was no literature in the class i am taking so i wanted to ask others. The way you put it make me understand better thanks.